# Remove the footer in mailchimp

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, mailchimp

I'm sending auto mail for my new subscribers via MailChimp, the mail is sent and every thing is fine but with a footer which gives user option to unsubscribe from the list...anyway I'm trying to disable that footer but all comes in vain, I tried to set the auto footer to false but nothing happens and here is sample of my code

```
var campaignCreateOpt = new campaignCreateOptions
            {
                list_id = listID,
                subject = Subject,
                from_email = from_Email,
                from_name = from_Name,
                template_id = 0,
                auto_footer = false
            };
```

Comment: I doubt mailchimp would let you do that - their whole business is responsible double-opt-in mailing list management.

Comment: I have no experience in creating campaigns through the API but I have in creating them manually and you will get warnings if you omit a option to unscribe even though this was after the campaign was sent. So I agree with @Rup here. They have a good chat support center maybe thay can help you out.

Comment: But I don't want my users to have option to unsubscribe from the list!!

Comment: Then I'd guess you can't use MailChimp. Agree with Martijn - ask them.

Comment: Mailchimp uses strict terms of use which are there for good reasons. One of them is preventing spam. They don't want to be blacklisted which could results in the blocking of all e-mail even not spam.

Comment: Okay I contact the the MailChimp chat support and they confirmed to me that it is not possible to disable the unsubscribe link in the mail and that every email must include an unsubscribe link.
Thanks guys :)

Comment: MailChimp checks to make sure your email contains an unsubscribe link. So while you can remove the footer, you'll need to keep the unsubscribe link in there somewhere.

Comment: The unsubscribe will always be there because according to the CAN-SPAM act there's a $16,000 fine per email sent if it's not. That's why mailchimp will never let you remove it :) If you find some other service that lets you not include the unsubscribe you'd be breaking a lot of laws. And the U.S. spam laws are actually more lenient than many countries...so just include the unsubscribe!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll have a better chance of your email getting out to most of your list if you allow the unsubscribe.

It's generally not smart to not give people an option to unsubscribe. If they do not see an unsubscribe option, they can mark you as spam. If you get too many "spam" complaints, your email may not reach the inboxes of even the people who would like to stay subscribed.

I doubt mailchimp will allow removal of the unsubscribe.

Answer (score 4):

Reasons:

1. Mailchimp's Terms of Service does not allow you to send an e-mail
   without the unsubscribe link. If you don't provide the unsubscribe
   link, they will insert it using the gray footer bar.
2. Also, if your account is free, and you don't use the REWARDS tag,
   they will also insert it through the gray bar.
3. The third probable reason is that if your code is complicated or
   broken, they might see it as an attempt to hide their UNSUBSCRIBE or
   REWARDS tag, so they will automatically add the gray bar to your
   e-mail.

Hope I helped you.

Source: http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/why-am-i-getting-a-gray-bar-or-a-2nd-footer-that-i-cant-edit

Answer (score 1):

I took the time to invest some further and maybe have to apologize to Mahmoud Ghoz and I will if you can test the following for me.

Probably the following is happening: your not including a *|UNSUB|* tag **or** you use a free account and not including a *|REWARDS|* tag? If this is the case, the footer will always be added no matter which value you use for the auto_footer property.

So try to include a *|REWARDS|* and *|UNSUB|*  tag in your mail and do a recheck. Please let's us know if it works. But like I said earlier you account can be temporary locked if you get to many spam warnings which could be the case if you not supply a unsub link.

Comment: OK didn't saw your comment but this corresponds with what they are saying.

Comment: look man the case is that I unsubscribe the mail by my self using code after the confirmation mail has been sent, so it doesn't make any sense to include a link in the mail to unsubscribe user from a list he already unsubscribed from...did you get my point?

Comment: @Islam Not really. Are you saying that your sending system mails via mailchimp? If so you don't sent system mails like confirmation mails through mailchimp. This is not what mailchimp is meant for.

Comment: That's what I recognized lately :)....did you now any mailing service which is accessible by code? I'm using ASP.net frame work 3.5, also I don't want to use any of windows live or gmail SMTPs as it is not legal!!

Comment: @Islam Why don't you use the smtp server of your ISP or hoster or run your own mail server for example hMailServer. You can use the System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient class for sending mails.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is not allowed for free user to do so

Comment: Yes that's what I also guess...if not why they allow in the API the bool auto-footer in the CampaginCreatOptions class which I have option to set it to true or false?

Comment: And also you can not hide the footer in the mail??

Comment: -1 This is guessing and BTW not true. See comments @Islam and my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, it turns out that my issue was a background image (in inline styles) in the footer. MC clearly thought I was trying to hide the unsubscribe link! I have removed and all is now good.